# Using R to save results of a lm model to a database

Tags: database, r, regression, data-manipulation

I'm trying to take the results of a linear regression performed in R and store those results in a database.

Specifically, what I'm after is the data in `coef(summary(myModel)`.  I can turn that into a dataframe and use `sqlSave()`, but the coefficient names are not a column in the dataframe.  How to I get the coefficients and the variable names into a single dataframe that can be saved using `sqlSave()`?

For clarity, I'm trying to store the data in a database table that has the columns:

> VariableName, Estimate, StdError, tValue, pValue

Is there an easier way to prepare this data to be stored in a database?   As an example here's what the results of `coef(summary(myModel))` gives:

```
                        Estimate  Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
 (Intercept)            51.52729727 2.623035966 19.64414439 1.941150e-58
 factor(person)507      -0.73663931 2.627215539 -0.28038785 7.793456e-01
 factor(person)713      -5.18612049 3.317899029 -1.56307363 1.189390e-01
 TransCnt               0.02658798 0.005682853  4.67863266 4.132888e-06
 factor(Month)5         0.67908563 1.119655304  0.60651312 5.445673e-01
 factor(Month)6         2.09595623 1.169658148  1.79193915 7.400639e-02
 factor(Month)7         2.91204838 1.333483558  2.18379024 2.964109e-02
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
datOut <- summary(myModel)$coef
datOut <- cbind(VariableName=rownames(datOut), datOut)
rownames(datOut) <- NULL
```

If you want to add your own column names:

```
colnames(datOut) <- c("VariableName", "Estimate", "StdError", "tValue", "pValue")
datOut
```

Answer (score 1):

The table produced by `summary.lm` is a matrix. You can coerce toa dataframe with `as.data.frame`

```
 df.coef <- as.data.frame( coef(summary(myModel)) )
```

The column names should be coerced to column names that have no spaces or quotes.

Comment: This gives me a dataframe of only 4 variables, the variable which contains the coefficient name is not a variable in the dataframe.  It's still a dimname, and sqlSave doesn't like that as far as I can tell.

Comment: Then use `cbind( rownames(df.coef), df.coef)`. And saying a function "doesn't like that" is not particularly helpful. If the problem is that the rownames are lost then the cbind maneuver will work. If the problem is that the rownames create an error, then you are toast, since dataframes always have rownames.